# Observable subscriber of properties stop working after remapping object by mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, knockout-mapping-plugin

ViewModel initialized and mapped from JSON inside `$(document).ready(..)`

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    viewmodel = new Order();
    var data = { json data };
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, viewmodel);
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
});

class Order
{
    ID: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    InvoiceAddress: KnockoutObservable<Address>;
    constructor()
    {
        this.ID = ko.observable(0);
        this.InvoiceAddress= ko.observable(new Address());
        this.InvoideAddress.subscribe(function(newvalue) { console.log(newvalue)}, this);
    }
}
```

Property `InvoiceAddress` of another type `Address` can be `null` 
When user create or delete `InvoiceAddress`, `$ajax` request will be send and new JSON object returned which contain updated data of whole `viewmodel`. 
Received data mapped to the same instance of viewmodel

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, viewmodel);
```

If state of `InvoiceAddress` was changed from `null` to existed object, then binding for `InvoiceAddress` stops working.

```
<input data-bind="value: InvoiceAddress().StreetName">
```

Question: Is it possible to keep binding working after "re-mapping"?

Update: "Stops working" -> subscribers of properties in the "InvoiceAddress" variable not firing after "InvoiceAddress" become `null` and remapped back to normal object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this.

```
<input data-bind="value: InvoiceAddress().StreetName">
```

Do this:

```
<div data-bind="with: InvoiceAddress">
    <input data-bind="value: StreetName">
</div>
```

Compare:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
    InvoiceAddress: ko.observable({StreetName: "Invoice Street"}),
    ShippingAddress: ko.observable(null),
    addShipping: function () { this.ShippingAddress({StreetName: "Shipping Street"}); },
    removeShipping: function () { this.ShippingAddress(null); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<b>Invoice Address</b>
<div data-bind="with: InvoiceAddress">
    <input data-bind="value: StreetName">
</div>

<b>Shipping Address</b>
<div data-bind="ifnot: ShippingAddress">-</div>
<div data-bind="with: ShippingAddress">
    <input data-bind="value: StreetName">
</div>

<button data-bind="click: addShipping">Add Shipping</button>
<button data-bind="click: removeShipping">Remove Shipping</button>
```

Using `with` also makes it easier to turn the whole thing into a template or a component.

Comment: If i remove mapping and generate new instance of "Address" type, then everything works fine - thanks. But using `this.InvoiceAddress(ko.mapping.FromJS(data));` will cause subscribers of properties stops firiing.

Comment: Could you please set up a Fiddle that demonstrates the issue? I will then try and fix it.

Comment: So problem was that mapping didn't use typescript `constructor` for creating new object. Because subscribers was created inside `constructor` of the class they wasn't created with mapping object.

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile and useful to other Typescript users if you outline your solution in an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted @Tomalak's answer because his answer put me in right direction to understand how Knockout's `Observables` works (documentation wasn't enough :))
But want to post a solution which solved a problem

Specific problem was that subscriber's stops firing after property was mapped by `knockout.mapping` plugin from `null` to new object

```
var orderData = {"ID":2,"InvoiceAddress":null}
ko.mapping.FromJS(orderData, {}, viewmodel);
//underlying object of observable this.InvoiceAddress is null
// then user added new address
var newAddressData = {"ID":3, "StreetName":"Third"} //returned by ajax request
ko.mapping.FromJS(newAddressData, {}, this.InvoiceAddress);
```

After that subscribers of properties inside `this.InvoiceAddress` stops firing.

Problem was because mapping plugin was created new instance of property type every time without using a constructor of type where subscriber was initialized.

Solution: create instance of underlying type before mapping

```
var newAddressData = {"ID":3, "StreetName":"Third"}
var tempAddress: Address = new Address();
ko.mapping.FromJS(newAddressData; {}, tempAddress);
this.InvoiceAddress(tempAddress);
```